# count the number of cells containing inf or -inf in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For a pandas dataframe `df`, if we want to count the number of cells containing `NaN` values, we can use `df.isna().sum().sum()`.  However, if we want to count the number of cells containing `inf` and `-inf` values. how to proceed?

Comment: to count positive use np.isposinf(df).sum().sum()
for negative np.isneginf(df).sum().sum()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `df.isin([np.inf, -np.inf]).sum().sum()`. ([Docu](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html#pandas.DataFrame.isin))